# Setting DataTable primary key

Tags: c#

```
objDataTable.Columns.Add("Student Id", typeof(int));
objDataTable.PrimaryKey = "Student Id";
```

am already tried many ways but i can't

in c# how to set primary key to this line , friends please help

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this out :

```
DataTable objDataTable = new DataTable();
objDataTable.Columns.Add("Student Id", typeof(int));
objDataTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { objDataTable.Columns["Student Id"] };
```

The property `PrimaryKey` is of `Type: System.Data.DataColumn[]` not string.